# How to use this for the main object on Object Literal Notation

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm learning about Object Literal Notation, but I'm trying to, or I think I'm doing is something a bit complex. For example

What I'm trying to accomplish is

- Initializa my object
- Store a jquery object
- Request for a JSON
- Build some html with that JSON
  and also use promise

(disclaimer, I'll hope that you can excuse my english and my lack of vision to point out clearly my issue)

```
var objeto = objeto || (objeto = {
    jsonUrl:"/something",
    container:{},
    triggerContainer:{}, 
    property1:{},
    init:function(var0,var1){
        this.container = $(var0);
        this.triggerContainer = $(var1);
        // ignoring some details I proceed to set my event
        this.loader()
    },
    loader:function(){
        // Here my scope is objeto, so far so good
        // But I have create self because my scope is about to change, am I right?
        self = this;
        this.triggerContainer.on("click",function(){
            // now, I'm going to request the json making a promise
            promiseME = jQuery.getJSON(self.jsonUrl);
            promiseME.done(self.Build);
            // NOW, I did it in this way beacuse I think it looks a bit cleaner
            // Of course my problem come next
        });
    },
    build: function(data) {
        /*
          here it is, now this is scoped for the promise, and I want to use data 
          to build some html, but I want to append to objeto.container, and I don't 
          know how to access, and I did even know how to pass a refence with .done()

        */
    }

});
```

I'm pretty sure, that I messing up something with this structure. Maybe I'm not using right. If so, could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: Try this: `promiseME.done(self.Build.bind(self));` or `promiseME.done(function () { self.Build(); });` - then you can access `this.container` in the `build` function

Comment: Hi @Ian you are right, and that is exactly what I need. I don't want to be annoying, so please excuse me If I ask you something else, did the done 'natural' scope, just go away? bind is something that I don't fully understand. Thanks

Comment: I would expect `var objeto = objeto || { ... };`

Comment: @mplungjan you mean, that with the () I'm blocking objeto to be in the scope?

Comment: I did not consider that, but (objeto={}) is unnecessary and possibly wrong as far as I can see

Comment: @raulricardo21 Well, the value of `this` depends on how you call the function. You are passing a reference to the function, and it's no longer being called by its owner (like it normally would be with `objeto.Build();`. `.bind()` returns a copy of the function and sets the value of `this` inside (its first parameter), no matter how it's called

Comment: @raulricardo21 Here's an example (basically the same thing as what you're doing, just done in a different way, demonstrating what `this` is): http://jsfiddle.net/GQuAX/